# Find the leader Node in a Spark Standalone Cluster with Zookeeper

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper

Hi I'm using Spark Standalone cluster with zookeeper
Before doing spark submit I need to find the leader node from the Spark-Cluster.

My Question is how to find the leader node across all the spark-master nodes:

1> Can it be fetched from Zookeeper ?

2> Is there is any API exposed by spark-master to check that ?

Comment: To make it clear, Find the zookeeper leader?

Comment: The Spark Master Node that is the Leader in the Spark cluster. The one with the state ALIVE. The problem is, spark doesn't allow to submit a job using :6066 REST API to the STANDBY nodes.

Comment: Do you have any result researching this issue?

Comment: @StefanRazvanFlorea It's been a while. You might take a look at https://github.com/s8sg/spark-py-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in a Spark cluster there is no leader node. There is one Alive Master, one or more Standby Masters and one or more Slaves. Secondly, when you submit a task to Spark, you don't need to know which one is the active master. You can provide all the Spark Masters ips and the cluster will take care of everything.

However, if you still want to see this information, the easiest way is by accessing the web ui which is usually available on port 8080. You can check the web ui port by looking at the Spark Master process details:

```
ps -ef | grep spark
```

> stefan   12682     1 15 09:50 pts/1    00:00:04 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -cp /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker **--webui-port 8081** spark://spark-ip:7077

By accessing this web ui at http://spark-ip:port, you will be available to see all the details about that master server. If you want to see this data in json format, add `/json` at the end.